# How to return an image as the response in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, httphandler

how i can cast the http handler response to image. 
I have created a handler which gives as follow which does some manipulation in the image

```
var absolutePath = context.Server.MapPath(imagePath);
var originalImage = Image.FromFile(absolutePath);
originalImage = new ImageMethods().AddWatermarkText(originalImage, "One Click");
context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
originalImage.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're having with this code?

Comment: this code is working fine but i want to get the response in a variable for further manipulation.

Answer (score 3):

The cast must be binary i.e byte array.

I think you are looking for something like this in handler

```
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/image"; ;
        System.IO.Stream strm = ShowImage(Number);


        if (strm != null)
        {
           byte[] buffer = new byte[100000];
           strm.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
           context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since you are representing image, you need to set the Image url to the handler. for eg Image1.ImageUrl="handler.ashx?param=idvalue"

Comment: can i get the response of the handler into another handler?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495964/image-server-security-asp-net-http-handler contains the further detail