# authentication gets shared in different applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm having two mvc-applications I need to debug at same time with different userLogins.

The two apps does not share any database or anything else.

The problem is: When I debug both apps at same time, and then login a user in app1 (default AspNet.Identity by the way). Then after that, I login a different user in app2. When I then go back to app1 and refresh the page, the user that is logged in in app2 gets logged in in app1.

So, is this is bug or how can I fix so I can be logged in as different users in my two apps?

EDIT: It works when I have the apps in different browsers (one in chrome and one in firefox)

Comment: The most of applications work like this why is this problem for you? Do you need this only for debugging?

Comment: Yes, it's only for debugging. Debug in different browsers works for now

Comment: You can open Chrome in incognito mode and login using different ID in separate window.

Answer (score 2):

as a solution just for debugging, you could open projects in different browsers, but if you want to solve it permanently you should know the mechanism of how membership login works cross different domains.

take a look to this: [Asp.net forms authentication and multiple domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056686/asp-net-forms-authentication-and-multiple-domains)

and another one: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/438319/Sharing-Authentication-Cookie-between-two-ASP-NET

Comment: Could you [summarise](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) the links here, in case they break?