# Is it possible to integrate Social Login in asp.net that will work over multiple domain

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, facebook-login, google-signin

I have 2 asp.net website hosted on 2 different domain in a same server and also sharing the same database.

How can I implement it like this way that user logged via social login provider(Facebook, Google) and they will be logged in other site automatically?

Can anyone give me some sort of reference about this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go with option of SSO

Please try the below solution that I found.

for Social Login
https://codeload.github.com/rustd/SocialLoginASPNET/zip/master

for Cross Domain (SSO)
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106439/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic

[Asp.net forms authentication and multiple domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056686/asp-net-forms-authentication-and-multiple-domains)

I hope this helps. let me know your outcome.