# How to handle session in asp.net web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have MVC web application. I have integrated my application with different different merchants, but different merchants can have same users. So lets say the same user has logged in two different merchants sites on same browser and redirects to my application. so lets say both users are redirected to our application. Now will there be two different sessions? If I want to implement session time-out,  how should I do it? and If lets say I open a new tab in the same browser which session will it acquire? If I do session.timeout, will both the session will be timed out?

Comment: Do different merchants have different URLs? Domain, top domain and subdomain I mean.

Comment: Yes, they have different URLs

Comment: To share sessions, which uses cookies by default, you could set the cookies to be used over multiple subdomains. It does not seem to be possible to set cookies up over multiple domains, which makes sense due to safety reasons. See this question for config of multiple subdomains: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056686/asp-net-forms-authentication-and-multiple-domains